Django- Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted
After upgrading python 3.6 to 3.8  in our django project we started to get core dump file upto 500mb which makes our kubernetes pods restart. There were no logs, no exception.
Upon debugging the core dump file with gdB got the following output,
#Reading symbols from /usr/local/bin/uwsgi...
#[New LWP 8]
#[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
#Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
#Core was generated by `uwsgi myapp.ini'.
#Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#50    ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.

(gdb) backtrace
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007f5998445859 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007f59984b026e in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7f59985da298 "%s\n")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:155
#3  0x00007f59984b82fc in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7f59985d844d "corrupted size vs. prev_size")
    at malloc.c:5347
#4  0x00007f59984b896b in unlink_chunk (p=p@entry=0x55dc42df1900, av=0x7f599860fb80 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:1454
#5  0x00007f59984b9e8b in _int_free (av=0x7f599860fb80 <main_arena>, p=0x55dc42dedf40, have_lock=<optimized out>)
    at malloc.c:4342
#6  0x00007f5998857bde in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#7  0x00007f5998697070 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#8  0x00007f599877b89d in _PyGC_CollectNoFail () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#9  0x00007f59987bcefd in PyImport_Cleanup () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#10 0x00007f59987a8610 in Py_FinalizeEx () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#11 0x000055dc3f2943e1 in uwsgi_plugins_atexit ()
#12 0x00007f59984698a7 in __run_exit_handlers (status=30, listp=0x7f599860f718 <__exit_funcs>, 
    run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true, run_dtors=run_dtors@entry=true) at exit.c:108
#13 0x00007f5998469a60 in __GI_exit (status=<optimized out>) at exit.c:139
#14 0x000055dc3f249415 in uwsgi_exit ()
#15 0x000055dc3f292f2b in end_me ()
#16 0x000055dc3f2965f7 in uwsgi_ignition ()
#17 0x000055dc3f29ae16 in uwsgi_worker_run ()
#18 0x000055dc3f29b394 in uwsgi_run ()
#19 0x000055dc3f245d44 in main ()


Unable to trace the issue in code or python packages.

python3.8
djang2.1.5
Ubuntu 20.04


Troubleshooting this without the source will not really be possible. It appears that the program crashes when freeing a resource, which would in turn be caused by that resource having gotten "corrupted" earlier, likely through some pointer bug or out of bounds access etc. If that's a bug in your code or in some library, I have no idea.


#3  0x00007f59984b82fc in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7f59985d844d "corrupted size vs. prev_size")

This error means: there is heap corruption (heap buffer overflow, using memory after it's been freed, etc. etc.) which GLIBC detected.
You should run your Python process under Valgrind, which should tell you were the bug is happening. Heap corruption bugs are ~impossible to debug without specialized tools (such as Valgrind).

I have some packages which are incompatible. will that be the reason for the issue?.

@Manjunath There is a bug somewhere. I told you how to narrow it down. Anything else is just guessing.
